# Vue js - passing props to components in vue rotuer

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following in my homepage

```
<info-panel type="updates"><info-panel/>
```

An expanded version of it exists on a different page. How do I pass the same prop to it in my router?

```
  path: '/infopanel',
        components: {
          default: InfoPanel,
          nav: PrimaryNav
        },
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way should work:

```
  path: '/infopanel',
    components: {
      default: InfoPanel,
      nav: PrimaryNav
    },
    props: { 
      default: true, 
      type: "updates" 
    }
  }
```

Here's the guide for what you're trying to achieve:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components

Comment: Hi, only passes it if I have a single component not a component object.